# unable to proceed to next steps when form is empty

Tags: vue.js

i have create vue app with wizard's like form by using ant-design steps. which user need to enter all the required form before proceed to next steps

```
<div>
<a-steps :current="current" size="small" style="width:70%; margin: auto;">
  <a-step v-for="item in steps" :key="item.title" :title="item.title" />
</a-steps>
<a-form :form="form">
  <div class="steps-content" v-if="steps[current].title=='form1'">
    <div style="width:97%; margin:auto;">
        <a-form-item label="Item1" :label-col="{ span: 24 }" :wrapper-col="{ span: 22 }">
          <a-input
            v-decorator="[
              'item1',
              { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'this is required!' }] }
            ]"
          />
        </a-form-item>
    <div class="steps-content" v-if="steps[current].title=='form2'">
      <div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
        <a-form-item
          label="item2"
          :label-col="{ span: 24 }"
          :wrapper-col="{ span: 22 }"
        >
          <a-input
            v-decorator="[
              'item2',
              { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'item2 is required!' }] }
            ]"
          />
        </a-form-item>
      </a-form>
   <div class="steps-action" align="right">
    <a-button v-if="current>0" style="margin-left: 8px" @click="prev">
      Previous
    </a-button>
    <a-button
      v-if="current == steps.length - 1"
      type="primary"
      @click="$message.success('Processing complete!')"
    >
      Finish
    </a-button>
    <a-button v-if="current < steps.length - 1" type="primary" @click="next">
      Next
    </a-button>
  </div>
```

this is example of structure of my form. i don't have any problem with this code. but i need when there are empty form in current, the user can't proceed to next steps when the user click on next button

Comment: does it have any built in validation? you can watch for failed validation and then prevent user from going to the next step.

Comment: all right thanks for your comment. i got what you meant. i'll share my working validators function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
checkSteps1() {
  this.form.validateFields((error) => {
    if (error) {
      return;
    }
    if (!error) {
      this.current += 1;
    }
  });
},
```

this is my working answer where i using if else statement to validates my form